# How to show missing value on Y-Axis of StackedBar100 in MSChart asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to show missing value on Y-Axis of StackedBar100 in MSChart asp.net.

[image: StackedBar Chart]

Comment: It's not "missing", there clearly just isn't room for the value. Where would you prefer the number be printed?

Comment: Mr Jonathon Reinhart.Do you have any idea about my problem?.How can i show this label value with enough space?please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Though, it is bit old question, thought of sharing for future searches' purpose

Two below magic lines can fix the problem.

1. Chart1.Series["Series2"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
2. Chart1.Series["Series2"].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;

Replace Chart1 and Series2 with appropriate names from your solution.

Comment: @JarYit, Did you try with this solution? and, if yes, Is issue resolved?